# testnet server won't get any btc from TP's TestNet Faucet. what is the reason?

Tags: bitcoind, testnet, regtest

I have generate bitcoin address from `testnet server`.

but I can't get any btc in those address. 
i tried many times and I failed.

can anyone explain me that is the reason? whay i can't get btc on those address.

note: i used regtest server for same purpose and my rpcport is 18332(regtest and testnet)

Answer (score 2):

I've just tested TP's faucet and it worked (green success text).

Are you sending to a testnet address (begins with m, n, or 2)? I'm thinking you may be inadvertently using Mainnet or Regtest mode (beginning with 1 or 3).

Ensure your Bitcoin.conf file has `testnet=1` in it, or use the `-testnet` flag on the command line. Also be certain your blockchain is fully synched (this will take many hours, unlike regtest mode)

Go into BitcoinCore's client, and try `getnewaddress` in the console (help > console). Then copy/paste that address into the faucet, complete the CAPTCHA, and the coins will have been sent. You will need to have a completely synched blockchain before the coins will "appear".

Comment: "**bitcoin.conf** `rpcuser=bitcoinrpc `
`rpcpassword=random string`
`testnet=1`"
also I didn't found `getchangeaddress` in bitcoin-cli. what is the problem???

Comment: note: main net and `testnet rpcpassword` is same

Comment: @ShahadatHossain sorry! I meant `getnewaddress`

Comment: I tried but I can't get any `testnet` bitcoin for those new addresses. what should I do now?

Comment: I don't know. You'd need to tell me specifically what the problem/error is

Comment: please see this link to more clear: `http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/39086/how-to-get-confirmed-balance-for-bitcoin-testnet-server?noredirect=1#comment45991_39086`

Comment: @ShahadatHossain I've just successfully sent coins to that address. However, check the unconfirmed Txs [here](http://tbtc.blockr.io/address/info/myVwyA9ooffVDqvbRJC4Kmspu2rDJBacTk), as it appears your previous attempt is unconfirmed, which suggests the faucet's daemon hasn't been working. I read your other post, so if you can rule out un-synched Blockchain then it looks like the faucet is the issue