# how to get confirmed balance for bitcoin testnet server?

Tags: bitcoind, testnet, testing

I can't get confirmed BTC from `https://tpfaucet.appspot.com/` server.

Tried many address and can't get balance with confirmation. for that reason my testnet server balance is always `0.0`

> **bitcoin.conf**
>
> rpcuser=bitcoinrpc
>
> rpcpassword=random string
>
> testnet=1
>
> address get by `getnewaddress`:`myVwyA9ooffVDqvbRJC4Kmspu2rDJBacTk`
>
> i used `https://www.blocktrail.com/tBTC` for know about my transaction and it's said it unconfirmed.

For that reason I am not able to test my server purpose.

**what should I do now???**

Comment: This looks a lot like your previous question, http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/39083/testnet-server-wont-get-any-btc-from-tps-testnet-faucet-what-is-the-reason, and there's no indication that you've tried any of the things that Wizard Of Ozzie suggested. All that we know is that it doesn't work. This is not very helpful for debugging.

Comment: it's not duplicate. I have edit the definition of body.  @NickODell